# how I append elements to xml?

Tags: java, xml

I have a xml file. I want to append new elements. When I added new items I control the xml and  in xml there is new entries without existing entries. I want to see all of them. why existing item entries was deleting?

**I mean I have record in xml And When I add new entries by this way , old entries is gone. Why? how can fix this?**

```
String filepath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\xxx.xml";
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);                             

Element newB = doc.createElement("Script");
Element newC = doc.createElement("Script_No");
newC.setTextContent(script_no);
Element newD = doc.createElement("Script_Name");
newD.setTextContent(script_name);
Element newE = doc.createElement("Script_Version");
newE.setTextContent(script_version);
Element newF = doc.createElement("Script_Modified_By");
newF.setTextContent(who);
Element newG = doc.createElement("Script_Result");
newG.setTextContent(result);
Element newH = doc.createElement("Script_Date");
newH.setTextContent(dateNow);

newB.appendChild(newC);
newB.appendChild(newD);
newB.appendChild(newE);
newB.appendChild(newF);
newB.appendChild(newG);
newB.appendChild(newH);
doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(newB);

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer2 = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult resultttt = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
transformer2.transform(source, resultttt);
```

I have this entry

[image]

---

I append a new values and my xml is this but ı dont want this:

### [image]

I wait it looks like this (but it donts): 
[image]

Comment: It may be helpful to show what you are expecting this method to output, versus what it actually outputs.

Comment: Using your code, I don't see any old elements deleted. For me, this code appends a new `<Script>` element as the last child of the document root element, just as your code indicates it should. Could you be dropping the other elements somewhere else along the way?

Comment: [Here](http://ideone.com/AW2A8) is the version of your code I used to test this.

Comment: my old elements gone  I mean its entries

Comment: I mean I have record in xml And When I add new entries by this way , old entries is gone. Why? how can fix this?

Comment: @ErsinGulbahar Again... can you edit your post above with examples to show what you are expecting, versus what you get?

Comment: As your code doesn't work for you, but [my code](http://ideone.com/AW2A8) works well enough for me, I suggest you try mixing those two until you've identified the one difference which causes yours to fail.

Comment: It is added new records?

Comment: @ErsinGulbahar, did you even click on [the link in my comment](http://ideone.com/AW2A8)? If so, you'll see the output section printing the document with both old and new content.

Comment: @MvG I look and it does not work.